# Inserting component in <Head> tag in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I want to change page title dynamically depending on web pages route, I have task to create and then import title component into the layout file but when I'm trying to do it nothing changes.

```js
const Title = ({ data }) => {
    function renderPageTitle(children) {
        let title =
            children.props.locale === 'ka'
                ? 'SHOPSHOP - პირველი ონლაინ შოპინგ მოლი'
                : 'SHOPSHOP - The First Online Shopping Mall';
        try {
            if (document?.URL?.includes('shop/')) {
                title = children?.props?.page?.blocks[0]?.shop?.title
                    ? `${children?.props?.page?.blocks[0]?.shop?.title} | ${title}`
                    : title;
            } else if (document?.URL?.includes('category')) {
                title = children?.props?.page?.blocks[1]?.content.title
                    ? `${children?.props?.page?.blocks[1]?.content.title} | ${title}`
                    : title;
            } else if (document?.URL?.includes('products')) {
                title = Object.values(children?.props?.page?.blocks[0]?.products)[0].name
                    ? `${Object.values(children?.props?.page?.blocks[0]?.products)[0].name} | ${title}`
                    : title;
            } else if (children?.props?.page?.title) {
                title = children?.props?.page?.title ? `${children?.props?.page?.title} | ${title}` : title;
            } else {
                return title;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            sendErrorLogs(error);
        } finally {
            return title;
        }
    }
    return <title>{renderPageTitle(data)}</title>;
};
```

And then

```
<Head>
    <Title data={children} />
</Head>
```

Comment: Remember that there are [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask), so: please look at your post, and then hit the [edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71783382/edit) and fix that missing markup (and making sure to properly indent that first block of code).

Answer (score 0):

For head tag manipulation I recommend the `react-helmet` package.

If you wanted to change the title dynamically it would look like this

```
class Component extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <>
        <Helmet>
          <title>{ insert dynamic title here }</title>
        </Helmet>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

Without the package you can edit `document.title` attribute when route changes or the view is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly I didn't understand your code, so that I couldn't adapt it to your page.

```
import Head from "next/head";

const meetupId = props => {
   return (
      <Fragment>
         <Head>
            <title>Meetup with meetapp</title>
            <meta name={props.meetupId.title} content={props.meetupId.description} />
         </Head>
         <MeetupDetail image={props.meetupId.image} title={props.meetupId.title} address={props.meetupId.address} description={props.meetupId.description} />
      </Fragment>
   );
};
```